# regular expressions in java matching first occurrence of time

Tags: java, regex

I want to set a pattern which will find a time from line

```
String line = "INFO  00:08:39 - End executing test11093 : Next time will be Tue Nov 05 00:13:27 GMT 2013"
Pattern pTime = Pattern.compile("[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]");
      Matcher mTime = pTime.matcher(line);
      String dateTime = null;
      while (mTime.find())
      {
          dateTime = mTime.group();       
      }
      System.out.println(dateTime);
```

The output is : 00:13:27, but I want to get only the first time!

Answer (score 2):

Try to add break; after dateTime = mTime.group(); or change the code this way

```
String dateTime = null;
if (mTime.find()) {
      dateTime = mTime.group();   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
if (mTime.find())
```

instead of:

```
while (mTime.find())
```